# Concatenating two 2d char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, concatenation

I wrote a small program to combine two 2d arrays. Here is the code:

```
#define MAX 7

int main(void) {
  int i, j;
  char *array1[] = {"Welt,", "bist", "du"};
  char *array2[] = {"noch", "zu", "retten?"};

  char final[MAX][MAX];
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // initialize ith names element with first name
    strcpy(final[i], array1[i]);
  }

  for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    // concatenate the last name to the firstname+space string
    strcat(final[i], array2[j]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i != 6; i++) {
    printf("%s", final[i]);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get really strange output like:

> Welt,bistbistdunochzuretten?uretten?en?

while what I want is this:

> Welt,bistdunochzuretten

As you can see it is not completely wrong. There should not be a space between the words.

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems were that in the second `for` you were doing `strcat(final[3], array2[j]);`, because `i` was 3 at that point and in the final `for` you were trying to print from `final[0]` to `final[5]`, when you only had defined `final[0]` to `final[3]` (where on final[0] to final[2] you had the names, and in final[3] you had all the last names concatenated which also exceeded the limit of characters), and without printing them in a new line it was hard to tell which string was what.

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 7

int main(void) {
    int i,j;
    char *array1[] = {"Welt","bist","du"};      
    char *array2[] = {"noch","zu","retten?"};   

    char final[MAX][MAX];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)    
        strcpy(final[i], array1[i]); //To initialize ith names element with first name

    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        strcat(final[j],array2[j]); //Concatanate the last name to the firstname+ space string

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", final[i]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not say it before, but try now including the libraries that I put in the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

1. The constant `MAX` is not large enough for your data. The string `"retten?"` contains seven characters plus one terminating byte. As such, `MAX` must be at least `8`, otherwise you get undefined behavior.
2. Your second loop contains uses the wrong index into `final[i]`. See point 3. for corrected versions.
3. The use of `strcat()` is wrong, you should be using `strcpy()` just like in the first loop. Together with point 2., your second loop should either look like this:

   ```
   for(j = 0; j < 3; i++, j++) {    //add increment for i
     strcpy(final[i], array2[j]);
   }
   ```

   or like this:

   ```
   for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
     strcpy(final[3 + j], array2[j]);    //derive the index from j
   }
   ```

---

Regarding Point 1, I always advise against using *any* compile time constants like `MAX`. My experience is that these are just bugs that are waiting to strike. Someday, someone will have a use case that exceeds the limit, and your program goes boom. I always allocate buffers to fit the strings that I need to store, leaving the available RAM as the only limit to my code. To this end, functions like `strdup()` and `asprintf()` are extremely handy because they already do the allocation for me.

Regarding Point 2, you should try to declare all your loop variables right inside the initialization statement. Like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // initialize ith names element with first name
  strcpy(final[i], array1[i]);
}
```

That way you don't run the danger of inadvertently using the loop variable after the loop / forgetting the initialization, etc. because your compiler will complain about the unknown variable.